# Issue using Material Radio Buttons in Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Platform: Ubuntu 14.0.1
NPM Version: 4.6.1

I have an Angular 2 application in which I am trying to use Material Radio Buttons. I have installed those using following command:

```
npm i @angular2-material/radio
```

I added following code in Module:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular2-material/radio';
```

Following is content of .html file (that breaks):

```
<md-radio-group>
          <md-radio-button value="1">Option 1</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="2">Option 2</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
```

When I run application I get following error in browser's console & my application breaks there:

```
nhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-radio-group' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-radio-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-radio-group' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" <md-radio-button value="2">Option 2</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>-->
        [ERROR ->]<md-radio-group></md-radio-group>
        <div class="page-card-separator">&nbsp;</div>
     "): AddProviderComponent@35:12 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'md-radio-group' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-radio-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-radio-group' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" <md-radio-button value="2">Option 2</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>-->
        [ERROR ->]<md-radio-group></md-radio-group>
        <div class="page-card-separator">&nbsp;</div>
     "): AddProviderComponent@35:12
at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.umd.js:8502)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.umd.js:16882)
at eval (compiler.umd.js:16805)
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at compile (compiler.umd.js:16805)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?1505985812318:192)
at Zone.run (zone.js?1505985812318:85)
at zone.js?1505985812318:451
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?1505985812318:225)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js?1505985812318:125) Error: Template parse errors:
```

Comment: Have you added `MdRadioModule` to your module imports?

Comment: Which file this should be?

Comment: That depends on your structure, but adding it to your root imports should make it available to all child components. So something like `app.module.ts`, probably...

Answer (score 9):

At first install `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk`, then import the related package inside `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Answer (score 5):

Please install Material 2 using the following commands:

- In your `package.json`, change/include `"@angular/material"` and `"@angular/cdk"` version `"2.0.0-beta.10"`
- In your terminal window, navigate to the folder in your project where `package.json` is located.
- Run the command `npm install`

For importing `MdRadioModule`, use the following:

```
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-274wa1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 2):

to solve this, following module to be imported for latest update.

import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/**radio**';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material7/angular_material7_radio_button.htm):

```
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material'
```

in the app modules

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Once I import the MatRadioModule in the child level module it works. I have the child level module called wizard.module.ts. I import MatRadioModule and then also include in the imports section of NgModule of wizard.module.ts file. Also once you import into the child level module, you can comment the import section from global module (app.module.ts) if you want. You don't need to import from both place.